# Could not write class router/Routes

Tags: java, playframework

I am using play framework, java, current play version of my project is 2.4.11. I want to upgrade it to 2.6.

While migrating the project I am getting this error in my routes file
" **Could not write class router/Routes because it exceeds JVM code size limits. Method documentation’s code too large!**"

This file was working fine before. I have shifted ~50 routes from it to another file routes2. Still compilation fails due to this error. Any idea?

structure of my routes file is like this:

```
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

->  /   routes2.Routes

# Home page
GET    /         controllers.LogController.loginFrm()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I shifted more routes and reduced the file size to ~64MB, nearly ~1000 routes and that's it, error goes away.